# Efficient representation for adjacency list and weights in directed graph

Tags: c++, graph, adjacency-list

I would like to get some feedback on storing adjacency lists for graphs.

I typically represent an adjacent list using a vector of vectors, e.g., `std::vector<std::vector<int>> adj_list`

For an edge E=(u,v), it is simply stored using `adj_list[u].push_back(v)`. If I want to remove this edge, I simply do

```
it = std::find(adj_list[u_idx].begin(), adj_list[u_idx].end(), v);
adj_list[u_idx].erase(it);
```

I also need a data structure for storing the weights corresponding to the edges. So originally, I was thinking of making another vector of vectors `std::vector<std::vector<double>> weights`, but it seems this is not the most efficient solution. Adding a new element in weights is simple, just like the above. All I have to do is `weights[u].push_back(weight_to_add)`. But removing a weight from the weights seems a bit more difficult than doing what I did above, i.e., finding the iterator, and then using that iterator to perform the deletion. I could find the index corresponding to the iterator in `adj_list`, and then delete the index from weights, but I don't know if that is the best way to go about this.

So instead of having two variables to represent the adjacency list and weights, I was thinking of making a single 3-D vector that stores both the adjacency list and weights. A vector of vector of vectors. The last dimension is size 2, that stores the node ID, v, and the corresponding weight of the edge. So really, it could just be a vector of vector of arrays. So something like `vector<vector<array<...>>>`. But the problem here is v is an `int` and the weights are doubles, so obviously I can't use arrays here. I could encapsulate the two inside a struct and then do something like `vector<vector<my_struct>>`. Or perhaps something like `vector<vector<pair<int,double>>>` would be better?

Any advice on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a

```
std::vector<std::vector<Entry>> adj_list
```

With Entry being

```
typedef struct {
    int node;
    double weight;

    bool operator == (const int e) const
    {
    return (node == e);
    }
} Entry;
```

Comment: What is the advantage of this over `std::pair`?

Comment: Well, you can do a pair as well, but then you have to do the "node lookup" differently when you do your "find()" since you most likely want to search for a specific NODEID, and not for euqality of the entire pair

Comment: Yes. That was going to be my next question. With the `struct`, how would you do the node lookup with `std::find`?

Comment: You leave it as it is right now, and just make sure that the == operator (as in the example above) checks the relevant parts.

Comment: ohh thanks. I didn't see that you had edited your answer.

Comment: maybe like this? (see above)

Comment: Edited ... this will allow you to check Entry == integer ... and the operator will automatically check the integer against Entry.node!

Comment: Thanks, what is the point of the `const` after the `(const int e)`?

Comment: Comparing two objects should not change either one of them: Neither the object "e", nor the local object. So the argument is const, and the operator itself is const as well

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use an adjacency list of pair of vector to do the same
`vector< pair<int, int> > adj[V];`

```
void printGraph(vector<pair<int,int> > adj[], int V) 
{ 
    int v, w; 
    for (int u = 0; u < V; u++) 
    { 
        cout << "Node " << u << " makes an edge with \n"; 
        for (auto it = adj[u].begin(); it!=adj[u].end(); it++) 
        { 
            v = it->first; 
            w = it->second; 
            cout << "\tNode " << v << " with edge weight ="
                 << w << "\n"; 
        } 
        cout << "\n"; 
    } 
}
```